# Issue with extra line space on Font Squirrel generated font in Firefox only

Tags: html, css, fonts

I’m currently redesigning my husband’s website, and though I’ve created a few basic websites  some years ago, I’m a bit of a novice and I’m just figuring things out as I go along…

I have a font that I’ve run through Font Squirrel, and I’m having an issue with how it displays in Firefox. Safari and Chrome seem to be working fine. The first line of text adds extra space above it. It is a display font and I have used it in many different areas of my site, including the navigation bar and many graphics and headings (not h1 or h2 tags per se, but many divs)—the one paragraph where I have used (in the sidebar on the index page) only puts the space above the first line. This is completely messing up the layout of my site, and I can’t find another font that works as well for the design.

I’ve tried setting the line-height to 1.2, and I’ve also tried the reset.css that I found on this site, but these don’t seem to work. I do already have a CSS reset included on my page that was recommended in the CSS manual I’m using.

Also, the CSS for the index page is still internal, so if you view the source you can see it. (I haven’t cleaned it up yet, so it might look a tad disorganized.)

The link to the test site is here:

http://www.californiaclassix.com/test/cc-indextest.html

Here is the CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'KenyanCoffeeRg-Regular';
  src: url('fonts/304BD0_0_0.eot');
  src: url('fonts/304BD0_0_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('fonts/304BD0_0_0.woff2') format('woff2'),
  url('fonts/304BD0_0_0.woff') format('woff'),
  url('fonts/304BD0_0_0.ttf') format('truetype');
  }
```

A couple of styles where I’ve used it:

```
.navbar { 
  font-family: KenyanCoffeeRg-Regular;
  font-size: 22px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 33px;
  background-color: rgb(25,25,25);
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  }

.lgredtext {
  font-family: KenyanCoffeeRg-Regular;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: rgb(222,59,33);
  }
```

The .lgredtext class is used for the word "SHOWROOM" in the second box down on the right side of the page.

I don’t know if including the html here would help. Again, it might be easier just to view the source on the actual page. It is lengthy, but I will be putting the CSS on an external sheet before we go live.

If I haven’t provided enough info, please let me know. As I said, I’m a novice, and I’m not sure what is needed to figure out the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans, So, would my code look like this?

```
 @font-face {
  font-family: 'KenyanCoffeeRg-Regular';
  src: url('fonts/304BD0_0_0.woff2') format('woff2'),
  url('fonts/304BD0_0_0.woff') format('woff'),
  ;
  }
```

I noticed the comment section said to add changes to the original post instead of commenting. I've read this forum a lot, but obviously, I'm not yet familiar with the posting etiquette. I'm open to corrections or suggestions.

Comment: protip: don't use `eot`, `svg`, `ttf` or `otf` sources. Simplify your problem surface by using WOFF only (`eot` is for IE8 and below - Microsoft no longer supports those. SVG hasn't been a legal font format in years, and fontsquirrel forgot to remove it. And because WOFF *is* the `ttf`/`otf` source, wrapped byte-for-byte, with an extra web header, you don't need ttf/otf if you already have WOFF, which you do). WOFF2 is up to you, but a lot of browsers don't support it yet, and unless you're doing subsetting, isn't really necessary.

Comment: So, would my code look like this?    *Added: Sorry, I'm having a difficult time formatting my comment. I can't hit the return button, and thus, can't post my code. I'll keep trying...

Comment: I added the my question to the bottom of my OP.

Comment: yeah, though for proper debugging I'd first reduce it to *just* WOFF, which will work on ever browser. No point in adding WOFF2 until that works (since the content of WOFF2 vs WOFF is identical, it's just compressed differently and allows for subset loading).

Comment: Okay thanks. 
I tried that but the issue is still there.

Comment: but at least now you've ruled out five possible different buggy conversions, so that helps everyone get to the bottom of the problem; good idea to update your post to reflect the new CSS you have - not as update, but as a change of the original data, because your situation is now different.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using styles for Firefox only. It would look something like this:

```
.lgredtext {
  font-family: KenyanCoffeeRg-Regular;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: rgb(222,59,33);
}

_:-moz-tree-row(hover), .lgredtext{
    font-family: KenyanCoffeeRg-Regular;
   font-size: 60px;
   color: rgb(222,59,33);
   line-height:1.2;
}
```

Please don't ask how the "underscore, colon, dash, moz, whatever" works. I don't know what it targets but it works on FF. If line height doesn't work you could try margins, padding or even border (maybe a transparent one). I shouldn't suggest this as it's not popular even though it's legitimate code; you could use a negative margin, but everyone says it's a bit hacky.

Comment: Don't worry, I won't ask. I probably wouldn't understand it anyway...

The line space isn't working. Maybe adding negative margins to the FF only will, but it will be tricky, because many of the places I use the font already utilize padding and margins. 

If the other suggestions I get don't work, I'll attempt this one. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For this problem in my case ["Fontie"](https://fontie.pixelsvsbytes.com/webfont-generator) works as a great solution; you need to upload your fonts and next check the suboption "Streamline vertical" metrics under "Optimizations vertical"